# importing a sql ddl file into Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql-server

how to import a SQL ddl file into ms sql server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL ddl file is just a bunch of queries, right? Just execute them with any SQL client or the management studio. I prefer [Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Managment Studio, or use the [SqlCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170207.aspx) line.